# unexpected keyword or identifier .ts(1434)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, solidity, keyword, uniqueidentifier

Can someone help me with finding out why I receive problems in VS code when coding in solidity even after installing the needed extensions?

I tried installing various different extensions individually and the issue persists.